# Track person's fall using skeleton data get from Kinect Xbox

Tags: c#, wcf, kinect

I’m suppose to create a C# wcf program for track the person’s fall by using X, Y and Z coordinates of the skeleton get from Kinect. Until getting coordinates, I’m successful. But when I use the algorithms to calculate velocity of the person’s movements, the program stops working. This is my code. Please help me to identify the mistake.

This is my code;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        Skeleton[] totalSkeleton = new Skeleton[6];
        private static Skeleton[] data;
        Skeleton skele;
        #region "Variables"


        private const double BodyCenterThickness = 10;
        private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;
        private readonly Brush centerPointBrush = Brushes.Blue;


        private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

        private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

        private readonly Pen trackedBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6);

        private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);

        private DrawingImage imageSource;


        private const double JointThickness = 3;

        private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;

        private const float RenderWidth = 640.0f;

        private const float RenderHeight = 480.0f;





        #endregion
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

            //After Initialization subscribe to the unloaded event of the form

            //We use this event to stop the sensor when the application is being closed.

            Unloaded += MainWindow_Unloaded;
        }
        void MainWindow_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //stop the Sestor

            sensor.Stop();
        }
        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            //Create a Drawing Group that will be used for Drawing

            this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

            //Create an image Source that will display our skeleton

            this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);
            //Display the Image in our Image control

            Image.Source = imageSource;
            try
            {
                //Check if the Sensor is Connected

                if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    //Start the Sensor

                    sensor.Start();

                    //Tell Kinect Sensor to use the Default Mode(Human Skeleton Standing) || Seated(Human Skeleton Sitting Down)

                    sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Default;

                    //Subscribe to te  Sensor's SkeletonFrameready event to track the joins and create the joins to display on our image control

                    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += sensor_SkeletonFrameReady;

                    //nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not

                    Message.Text = "Kinect Ready";

                    Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

                    Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                    //  Skeleton firstSkeleton = (from trackskeleton in totalSkeleton where trackskeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.
                    //// Tracked
                    //select trackskeleton).FirstOrDefault();

                    //  this.MapJointsWithUIElement(firstSkeleton);
                    // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames

                    this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
                }

                else if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.Disconnected)
                {
                    //nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not

                    Message.Text = "Kinect Sensor is not Connected";

                    Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

                    Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                }

                else if (sensor.Status == KinectStatus.NotPowered)
                {
                    //nice message with Colors to alert you if your sensor is working or not

                    Message.Text = "Kinect Sensor is not Powered";

                    Message.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                    Message.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

        }

        private void MapJointsWithUIElement(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            Point mappedPoint = this.ScalePosition(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position);
            //Point mappedPointw = this.ScalePosition(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position);
            myhandPosition.Content = string.Format("X:{0},Y:{1}", mappedPoint.X, mappedPoint.Y);
            //myhandPosition.Content = string.Format("X:{0},Y:{1}", mappedPoint.X, mappedPoint.Y);


            Canvas.SetLeft(righthand, mappedPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(righthand, mappedPoint.Y);
            //float A = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item1;

        }

        public void verificaCaduta(SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame, Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {

            }
        }

        void sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            //declare an array of Skeletons

            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[1];
            Skeleton firstSkeleton;
            Skeleton[] data;
            // float A = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane.Item1;


            //Opens a SkeletonFrame object, which contains one frame of skeleton data.

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonframe = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {

                //Check if the Frame is Indeed open

                if (skeletonframe != null)
                {
                    Skeleton[] skeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonframe.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonframe.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);
                    // Copies skeleton data to an array of Skeletons, where each Skeleton contains a collection of the joints.


                    //draw the Skeleton based on the Default Mode(Standing), "Seated"
                    //skeletonframe.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                    if (sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode == SkeletonTrackingMode.Default)
                    {
                        //Skeleton firstSkeleton = (from trackskeleton in skeletons
                        //where trackskeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                        Skeleton playerSkeleton = (from s in skeletonData where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked select s).FirstOrDefault();

                        DrawStandingSkeletons(skeletonData);

                        // float x = playerSkeleton.Position.X;
                        //Skeleton firstSkeleton;
                        //DrawingContext drawingContext;

                        //Joint rightHand = playerSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

                        //  skeletonframe.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);
                        //float A = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item1;
                        //float B = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item2;
                        //float C = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item3;
                        //float D = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item4;
                        //float x = rightHand.Position.X;
                        //float y = rightHand.Position.Y;
                        //float z = rightHand.Position.Z;

                        //float powA = A * A;
                        //float powB = B * B;
                        //float powC = C * C;


                        //float numerater = x + y + z + D;
                        //float denominater = powA + powB + powC;

                        //float distance = numerater / (float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominater);
                        ////  Console.WriteLine("probability " + distance);

                        //if (distance <= 0.60)
                        //{
                        //    MessageBox.Show("fall detection");
                        //}

                    }

                    //else if (sensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode == SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated)
                    //{
                    //    Draw a Seated Skeleton with 10 joints

                    //    DrawSeatedSkeletons(skeletons);
                    //    skeletonframe.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

                    //}
                }
            }
        }


        private void DrawStandingSkeletons(Skeleton[] skeletons)
        {
            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {

                //Draw a Transparent background to set the render size or our Canvas

                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
                //If the skeleton Array has items

                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {

                    //Loop through the Skeleton joins

                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {

                        RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);



                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {

                            this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);

                        }

                        else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                        {

                            dc.DrawEllipse(this.centerPointBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position),
                                BodyCenterThickness, BodyCenterThickness);

                        }
                    }
                }
                //Prevent Drawing outside the canvas

                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
            }

        }

        private void DrawSeatedSkeletons(Skeleton[] skeletons)
        {



            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {

                //Draw a Transparent background to set the render size

                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));



                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {

                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {

                        RenderClippedEdges(skel, dc);



                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {

                            this.DrawBonesAndJoints(skel, dc);

                        }

                        else if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                        {

                            dc.DrawEllipse(this.centerPointBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(skel.Position), BodyCenterThickness, BodyCenterThickness);

                        }
                    }
                }

                //Prevent Drawing outside the canvas

                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight));
            }

        }


        private static void RenderClippedEdges(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
            {

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(

                    Brushes.Red,

                    null,

                    new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
            {

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(

                    Brushes.Red,

                    null,

                    new Rect(0, 0, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));

            }
            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
            {

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(

                    Brushes.Red,

                    null,

                    new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));

            }



            if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
            {

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(

                    Brushes.Red,

                    null,

                    new Rect(RenderWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, RenderHeight));

            }

        }

        public void DrawBonesAndJoints(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            float x1, y, z;


            // Render Torso

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Spine);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.Spine, JointType.HipCenter);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight);
            // Left Arm

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft);

            // Right Arm

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight);
            // Left Leg

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft);



            // Right Leg

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight);

            this.DrawBone(skeleton, drawingContext, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight);
            // Render Joints

            foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {

                Brush drawBrush = null;



                if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                {

                    drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;

                }

                else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
                {

                    drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;

                }
                if (drawBrush != null)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint.Position), JointThickness, JointThickness);
                    Message2.Text = joint.Position.X.ToString();
                    Message4.Text = joint.Position.Y.ToString();

                    //if (joint.Position.X > 0.4)
                    //{
                    //    Message3.Text = "fall";
                    //}


                    //dovrei calcolare la distanza dal pavimento
                    //joint head
                    //float addendo1 = A * firstSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.X;

                    x1 = joint.Position.X;
                    y = joint.Position.Y;
                    z = joint.Position.Z;


                    //float addendo1 = A * skeleton.Position.X;
                    //float addendo2 = B * skeleton.Position.Y;
                    //float addendo3 = C * skeleton.Position.Z;

                    //float addendo1_d = A * A;
                    //float addendo2_d = B * B;
                    //float addendo3_d = C * C;


                    //float numeratore = addendo1 + addendo2 + addendo3 + D;
                    //float denominatore = addendo1_d + addendo2_d + addendo3_d;

                    //float distanza = numeratore / (float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominatore);
                    ////  Console.WriteLine("probabile caduta " + distanza);

                    //if (distanza <= 0.60)
                    //{
                    //    Message3.Text="fall detection";
                    //}      

                }
                // joint.Position.Z

            }



        }

        private void DrawBone(Skeleton skeleton, DrawingContext drawingContext, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1)
        {
            Joint joint0 = skeleton.Joints[jointType0];

            Joint joint1 = skeleton.Joints[jointType1];

            // If we can't find either of these joints, exit

            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked || joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {

                return;

            }

            // Don't draw if both points are inferred

            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
            {

                return;

            }

            // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked

            Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;



            if (joint0.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && joint1.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {

                drawPen = this.trackedBonePen;

            }

            drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint0.Position), this.SkeletonPointToScreen(joint1.Position));

        }
        /// <summary>

        /// Maps a SkeletonPoint to lie within our render space and converts to Point

        /// </summary>

        /// <param name="skelpoint">point to map</param>

        /// <returns>mapped point</returns>

        private Point SkeletonPointToScreen(SkeletonPoint skelpoint)
        {            // Convert point to depth space. 

            // We are not using depth directly, but we do want the points in our 640x480 output resolution.

            DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skelpoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);

            return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
        }



        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private Point ScalePosition(SkeletonPoint skeletonPoint)
        {
            DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.
            MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skeletonPoint, DepthImageFormat.
            Resolution640x480Fps30);
            return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
            //textBox1.Text = depthPoint.X.ToString();

        }



    }


}
```

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? What error do you get?

Comment: Where are your algorithms that you use to calculate the velocity. Maybe I skimmed over it but all I see is the basic stuff to draw the skeleton to the screen and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is my algorithm to detect the fall.

```
                   float A = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item1;
                   float B = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item2;
                   float C = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item3;
                   float D = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item4;
                   float x = rightHand.Position.X;
                   float y = rightHand.Position.Y;
                   float z = rightHand.Position.Z;

                   float powA = A * A;
                   float powB = B * B;
                   float powC = C * C;


                   float numerater = x + y + z + D;
                   float denominater = powA + powB + powC;

                   float distance = numerater/(float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominater);
                    Console.WriteLine("probability " + distance);

                    if (distance <= 0.60)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("fall detection");
                    }
```

when we run the program its not detect fall.